# Preparing data for surface3d in R. More fast code please

Tags: r, interpolation, weighted-average

I am trying to get "surface3d plot" from 120,000 rows of csv data, but my code is too slow and the processing time will be over 12 hours.
Which place should be changed?
( interp() process time also will be over 12 hours. If it is possible, I want to merge mk_surface_data() and interp(). Is it possible?)

```
library(rgl)
library(data.table)
library(akima)

fv <- cmpfun(function(vec) {
    return(vec[is.finite(vec)])
})

mk_surface_data <- cmpfun(function(mat, mean_range = 2, x_div = 100, y_div = 100,defalut_z = 0){

  x <- mat[,"x"]
  y <- mat[,"y"]

  min_x <- min(fv(x))
  max_x <- max(fv(x))
  min_y <- min(fv(y))
  max_y <- max(fv(y))

  sa_x <- max_x - min_x
  sa_y <- max_y - min_y

  step_x <- sa_x / x_div
  step_y <- sa_y / y_div

  surface_m <- matrix(nrow=0,ncol=3)

  for(x in 0:x_div){

    base_x_range <- min_x + (step_x * x)
    min_x_range <- base_x_range - (mean_range * step_x)
    max_x_range <- base_x_range + (mean_range * step_x)

    for(y in 0:y_div){

      base_y_range <- min_y + (step_y * y)
      min_y_range <- base_y_range - (mean_range * step_y)
      max_y_range <- base_y_range + (mean_range * step_y)

      all_z <- mat[((min_x_range < mat[,"x"]) & (max_x_range > mat[,"x"]) & (min_y_range < mat[,"y"]) & (max_y_range > mat[,"y"])),c("z")]

      if(length(fv(all_z)) > 0){
        insert <- c(base_x_range,base_y_range,weighted.mean(all_z,na.rm=T))           
      }else{
        insert <- c(base_x_range,base_y_range,defalut_z)
      }  

      surface_m <- rbind(surface_m,insert)
    }
  }
  colnames(surface_m) <- c("x","y","z")
  return(as.matrix(surface_m))
})

# main process

mean_range = 2
x_div = 1000
y_div = 1000
defalut_z = 0

mat <- as.matrix(fread("target_file.csv"))
sdf <- mk_surface_data(mat, mean_range, x_div, y_div,defalut_z)
interpolated <- interp(sdf[,"x"], sdf[,"y"], sdf[,"z"])
plot3d(sdf[,"x"], sdf[,"y"], sdf[,"z"])
surface3d(interpolated$x, interpolated$y, interpolated$z,col="green")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line of code that always raises red flags in terms of efficiency is:

```
surface_m <- rbind(surface_m,insert)
```

Basically you are growing the matrix `surface_m` one row at a time within your innermost loop, which can be extremely inefficient (see the second circle of [the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for details). You can construct `surface_m` more efficiently with something like:

```
surface_m <- t(apply(expand.grid(y=0:y_div, x=0:x_div), 1, function(yx) {
  y <- yx[1]
  x <- yx[2]
  base_x_range <- min_x + (step_x * x)
  min_x_range <- base_x_range - (mean_range * step_x)
  max_x_range <- base_x_range + (mean_range * step_x)
  base_y_range <- min_y + (step_y * y)
  min_y_range <- base_y_range - (mean_range * step_y)
  max_y_range <- base_y_range + (mean_range * step_y)

  all_z <- mat[((min_x_range < mat[,"x"]) & (max_x_range > mat[,"x"]) & (min_y_range < mat[,"y"]) & (max_y_range > mat[,"y"])),c("z")]

  if (length(fv(all_z)) > 0){
    insert <- c(base_x_range,base_y_range,weighted.mean(all_z,na.rm=T))           
  } else {
    insert <- c(base_x_range,base_y_range,defalut_z)
  }  
  return(insert)
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I tried your code and the process time was 4 hours.
Thanks a lot.